# Accessing current state in another function

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm new to React but I'm determined to figure this out.

I understand the basic principles of State in React but I'm missing something in understanding how and where they live. I'd like to have one function to set the state of a value and then in another function, perform some logic based on the current state of that value. However, I cannot access the current state of the value in the other function, instead I only get the state that is set on page load.

Here's what I have:

```
  async limit() {
    let goalName = await get_goal_name();
    let goal = await get_goal_target(goalName);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      targetGoal: goal
    }));
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      minutes: prevState.minutes + 1,
    }));
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000); //change to 60000
    this.limit = this.limit();
    this.ogDiv = this.ogDiv();
  }

  ogDiv() {
    console.log("Minutes TICK: ");
    console.log(this.state.minutes);
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>
        <div>You've been here {this.state.minutes} minutes and the limit is {this.state.targetGoal} minutes</div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DomainGoalTimer />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As you can see I'm trying to access the state of `tick` inside the function `ogDiv()`. Now I only get the state that is set on page load `(0)`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You call `tick` every second, but you only call `ogDiv` on mount. `minutes` in your state will not have been updated before `ogDiv` is run.

Comment: ohh that makes sense, how should I do call `ogDiv` every time `tick` is called then?

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing what you want to do inside of `ogDiv`.

Comment: I want to change the content inside of my render function based on certain logic that comes from the `tick` function

Comment: I think what I'm most confused about, which is why it's so puzzling to me, is how and when functions are called in React. I understand that `tick` is called every second (b/c of the first line in `componentDidMount` but I don't really understand how/when `componentDidMount` is called. So if I want to change the content of my `div` inside of `render()`, I want logic inside of `ogDiv` to determine when to change the content (based on what second has passed inside `tick`).

Comment: Then you most likely want to do your `ogDiv` logic inside of the `tick` function, so that it is run every second, just like the current `tick`.

Comment: I get that, but I wanted to seperate the logic. I know that's a simple solution though

Answer (score 0):

You should bind this these functions in constructor or you can turn them into arrow function.

```
class DomainGoalTimer extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.limit = this.limit.bind(this);
    this.ogDiv = this.ogDiv.bind(this);
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you have already bounded funcs, dont forget add previous state:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      minutes: prevState.minutes + 1,
}));
```